Ubuntu 23.04 stopped boot up
i have been using ubuntu 23.04 for a while.
last week, it suddenly stopped booting up and instead during the boot up gets stuck at this screen:
enter image description here
I tried to install a fresh ubuntu (24.04) on a different hard drive (a new ssd) but that one too encountered an unknown error, and I couldnt install the new ubuntu.
then i though my bios may needs to be updated, so I updated the bios and still it gets stuck in the same screen during the boot up:
enter image description here
I have to mention that i am using an MSI motherboard, as i remember there was some special setting for running linux on MSI.
I also have a windows on my computer that boots up just fine.
Anyone here could help me? any thought on what is the issue and how i migt be able to solve it?

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

As I said earlier, I am planning to move forward to Ubuntu 24.04, however, I cannot install it due to the same issue, which i suspect is with the motherboard settings and the update in the kernel or something like that.

Questions about installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on your system would be on-topic as that is a supported release of Ubuntu. Ubuntu 23.04 is off-topic now, it's upgrade path gone as it release-upgraded to 23.10 which is now EOL as well; so a re-install will be required. Questions about 23.04 however aren't on-topic here due to EOL status.

thank you for your clarification,
I mentioned, I tried to install a fresh 24.04 version, However it did not work, for the same reason.
That's why I need help with my system,

Does the boot show a grub menu? Boot and assert ESC repeatedly. How did you attempt to install 24.04? USB? Did you arrange the BIOS to boot from USB? My initial impression is the error that is causing the problems is not one being displayed. What display hardware are you using (NVIDIA)? More information is required.

yes, it shows the grub menu.
I tried to install with a bootable USB, on a different hard drive.
I use an intel arc a770 graphic card. and have been using it for almost a year with the same system and has been working just fine.
to give you more information, I have a 13400 core i5 cpu and a PRO B760M-A WIFI DDR4 motherboard

Staying with 23.04 - does it boot from the the previous kernel? (Select this from the grub menu.) Failing that, does it boot in Recovery mode?

I finally found out the issue.
I have set TimeShift to keep two snapshots of the system and update it every month, For some reason Timeshift took three more and occupied the whole Home/root drive.
by booting into the live boot-able i found this out and after removing the old snapshots the system worked just fine.
now i reinstalled with a separate home and root to prevent this from happening again.
thank you for your help.
